# Handsontable: "minSpareRows" is adding twice as much its number

Tags: javascript, handsontable

For some reason, minSpareRows is adding twice as much as it's told when the data source is an object. Is this a bug?

Here's a VERY simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/hrPbL/3/

```
var data = [
     { link: { url: 'http://test1.com', label: 'test 1' } }
 ];

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#example').handsontable({
         data: data,
         cells: cellRenderer,
         minSpareRows: 2, // !!!!!
         columns: [
             { data: "link" }
         ]
     });
 });
```

And here's an even simpler example: http://jsfiddle.net/hrPbL/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = [
        { link: { url: 'http://test1.com', label: 'test 1' }}
    ];

    $('#example').handsontable({
        data: data,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        columns: [{
            data: "link"
        }]
    });
});
```

Any idea what's going on here??

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
$('#example').handsontable({
    data: data,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    columns: [ 
        {data: "link.url"},{data: 'link.label'}
     ]
});
```

Change this  **columns: [{
            data: "link"
        }]**     to   **columns: [ 
            {data: "link.url"},{data: 'link.label'}
         ]**

Comment: That works but it's not the desired outcome. Although it's weird that it affects minSpareRows.

Comment: @jmrjulian Can you link to the issue on github? It something is weird it is most often a bug